# Calling a python function with options from shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script which takes various options from the command line

e.g.

-runs with gui

```
python myscript.py -gui
```

-runs without requiring user prompts

```
python myscript.py -aut
```

-runs with input data taken from input.py

```
python myscript.py input.py
```

-and combinations of the above e.g. runs automatically taking input from input.py

```
python myscript.py -aut input.py
```

I would like to be able to call this from anywhere on my linux box. How can I do this? I have tried aliasing this in my .bashrc file, but using this method it is unable to accept any of the input options. I have also tried

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/above_myscript/`

but this only recognises the command if I type myscript, not python myscript . Typing just myscript obviously is unable to run the python script.

I have also tried writing a shell script which I could call.

```
#!/bin/bash
#file: myscript.sh

python '/path/to/folder/above_myscript/myscript.py'
```

However, again I am also unable to pass any options to it. What is the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the top of your **myscript.py** file and run `chmod +x myscript.py` on it you should be able to run `myscript.py` without needing to put `python` before it. This should let you use the `PATH` changing method you had before.

Comment: This nearly works for me. However, within myscript.py I have a subprocess command which calls `myscript_gui.py`, which then calls some image files. `myscript.py` can't find `myscript_gui.py` unless I explicitly include the path to this file and `myscript_gui.py` can't find the image files either. Is there a way for python to use what's already on my linux path to run the gui?

Comment: @218 http://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/3447365 This answer shows you how to get the directory of the script you are calling. If the myscript_gui.py script is in the same directory, which i'm assuming it is? Then you can prepend the directory path to where you call it and it should work :)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how to do that - the link is for bash script which python can't read so `DIR=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )` just returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: @218 Sorry I must have derped big time, was answering a bash question a the time also :) In python you can use `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` to get the directory that the script is in. You can then attach this to the start of your `myscript_gui.py` script to get the location of it :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
python /path/to/folder/above_myscript/myscript.py
```

or this :

```
cd /path/to/folder/above_myscript && python myscript.py
```

on your shell script.